# Spinner value from Firebase, On new data add spinner Item

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have done my project using Spinner and Firebase realtime database read. On newly add value, spinner will not remove the old value, how to do it?

Here the preview
https://photos.app.goo.gl/jYTyJvcDpqBeGDTg9

"POS" is the new item I add on my database, here the preview https://photos.app.goo.gl/mH14qQ54ra3ULBZH8

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.tujuan_spinner);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Spinner_Tujuan");

    spinnerDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerDataList);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    retrieveData();
```

When I add new Value, spinner still keep old value which its become dupilicate value. How can I remove old value when new Value are inserted?

```
    //HERE
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {
            spinner.setSelection(i);
            final String value =spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if (value.equals("SILA PILIH")){
                //DO nothing

            }if (value.equals("Pegawai")){
                bukasenaraiPegawai();
            } else {
                admin.setValue(value);
                openDialogInfo();
                spinner.setSelection(0);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}

public void retrieveData(){
    listener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot item : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                spinnerDataList.add(item.getValue().toString());
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time your `onDataChange` method is called, the `dataSnapshot` contains a snapshot of all data at `databaseReference`. So you'll need to clear the existing data from the `spinnerDataList` to prevent duplicates:

```
listener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        spinnerDataList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot item : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            spinnerDataList.add(item.getValue().toString());
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```